# respondsToSelector Cannot be Called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates

**Sorry about the confusion.
What I want to do:
   enter a string in a textfield in a view(EnterCommandViewController) and click save button, which will dismiss current view and go back to another view(DetectionViewController) and show the string in the UILabel in current view(DetectionViewController). So I have put define the delegate protocol in EnterCommandViewController, my question is that why the respondToSelector, which is used to check whether someone is listening does not work.**

---

I am really a beginner in iOS, I am right now writing a delegate to send text got form `UITextField` to a `UILabel`, But I found that the `respondToSelector` cannot be called by using `NSLog` for testing.

Below is my code for reference:

EnterCommandViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RscMgr.h"

@protocol EnterCommandDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) commandEntered:(NSString*)command;

@end

@interface EnterCommandViewController : UIViewController <RscMgrDelegate>
{
 RscMgr* rscMgr;
 __weak IBOutlet UITextField *inputTextField;

 __unsafe_unretained id<EnterCommandDelegate> delegate;
}

-(void)sendMessage:(NSString*)message;

- (IBAction)cancelPressed;

- (IBAction)savePressed;

@property (nonatomic,assign)id delegate;

@end
```

EnterCommandViewController.m

```
#import "EnterCommandViewController.h"

@interface EnterCommandViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    @private
    BOOL connected;
}

@end

@implementation EnterCommandViewController

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
rscMgr = [[RscMgr alloc] init];
[rscMgr setDelegate:self];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

inputTextField.text=@"";
[inputTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
inputTextField.delegate = self;
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
inputTextField.delegate = nil;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)cancelPressed {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}

- (IBAction)savePressed {
//is anyone listening

NSLog(@"the command is %@",inputTextField.text);
  NSLog(@"Checking -- SomeMethod is listening");
if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(commandEntered:)]){
    NSLog(@"SomeMethod is listening");
    //send delegate function with the command entered by the user
    [delegate commandEntered:inputTextField.text];
}
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

DetectionViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EnterCommandViewController.h"

@interface DetectionViewController : UIViewController <EnterCommandDelegate>{

__weak IBOutlet UILabel *showCommand;
}
- (IBAction)showSettings:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

@end
```

DetectionViewController.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DetectionViewController.h"

@implementation DetectionViewController


- (IBAction)showSettings:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

}

-(void) viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
showCommand.text=@"";
EnterCommandViewController* enterCVC = [[EnterCommandViewController alloc] init];
    enterCVC.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - EnterCommandDelegate function(s)

-(void) commandEntered:(NSString *)command{
//    showCommand.text = command;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"command: %@",command);
    [self->showCommand setText:command];

});
}
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear, could you edit your original post and try to improve the real question? what you want to achieve?

Comment: How you are transitioning from `DetectionViewController` to `EnterCommandViewController ` through storyboard segue or by pushing/presenting then show that code also

Comment: Your question is not clear what you exactly want ?

Comment: @Anil Varghese I am using storyboard to do the transition

Comment: @Abdrea are the updates make it more clear? sorry about the delay

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the `delegate` properly.

```
EnterCommandViewController* enterCVC = [[EnterCommandViewController alloc] init];
    enterCVC.delegate = self;
```

This is not the way of setting the `delegate` in your case, since you are not using the created instance of `enterCVC, instead a new instance is created from the storyboard when you are transitioning to`EnterCommandViewController `(From your comment its clear that you are using the storyboard for this).

So what you can do is you should the `delegate` from `prepareForSegue` in `DetectionViewController` like

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     // Get reference to the destination view controller
     EnterCommandViewController* enterCVC = [segue destinationViewController];
     enterCVC.delegate = self;
}
```